# Best practice for passing JWT from server to client

Tags: reactjs, express, jwt

I'm building an app with user authentication and I've been having issues with handling JWT with React and Express. I'm setting the cookie in the server response and I can see the cookie in the browser on my client. However, when I make a request to my server after that req.cookies.token is still undefined.

```
# server/routes.js

// return authenticated user
app.get('/auth', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.cookies.token)
})

// register user
app.post('/user', async (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body,
          hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

    let user = new User({ 
        name: name.toLowerCase(), 
        email: email.toLowerCase(), 
        password: hash,
        picture: null
    })

    try {
        let newUser = await user.save()

        let token = jwt.sign({
            id: newUser.id,
            name: newUser.name,
            picture: newUser.picture
        }, config.secret)

        res.status(200).cookie("token", token, { 
            domain: "localhost",
            httpOnly: true, 
            secure: false
        }).send('success')
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

In my server file I'm importing and using the cookie parser library like such:

```
# index.js

var express = require('express')
var app = express()

var cookies = require('cookie-parser')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cors = require('cors')

var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var config = require('./config')

app.use(cookies())
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true
}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))

require('./routes')(app)
```

Also since I'm setting httpOnly for the cookie shouldn't I not be able to see the cookie on the client? I'm considering just setting the token in authorization header from the client like this

```
# hoc/authenticate.js

if(cookies.get('token')) {
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${cookies.get('token')}`
}
```

Also would going about authentication in this manner not scale well? Like if I have 1000 users connecting to my site would there be overlapping issues with cookies?

Comment: have you solved this?

Comment: Well I ended up just setting the cookie from the server (not as httpOnly: true) and checking for the token cookie on the client and appending it to every request using axios.defaults.headers.common.. so not really